# Looping through a list of items to get their foreignkey value

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a Feed model with the following field:

```
 class Feed(models.Model)
        authority=models.ForeignKey(Authority,blank=True,null=True)
```

I have a queryset of authority called `followed_authority` in which I want to get the corresponding feeds from each of the authority in `followed_authority`
The obvious thing for me is to use a `for` loop through `followed_authority` which I think its inefficient as the instanaces in `following_authority` and their corresponding feeds are very large.Kindly help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct thing to do is to always start from the model you want to get.

```
Feed.objects.filter(authority__in=followed_authority)
```